# error sending multiple files to aws s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm learning about AWS IoT using Raspberry Pi and python. Problem I came across is the following:

In main function on event detection a picture is been taken and saved on the Pi. After picture is saved a function store_to_bucket is called and i'm passing two parameters: a path, where picture is stored and a date string. Everything is working fine for the first time. Second function call gives me the following error:

ClientError: An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the PutObject operation: The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.

Code

```
ACCESS_KEY_ID   =   open("/mykey/path/key.txt", "r")
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = open("/mykey/path/skey.txt", "r")
BUCKET_NAME =   open("/mykey/path/bucket.txt", "r").read()

data = open(path, 'rb') 
    ext = '.jpg'    

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID.read(),
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY.read(),
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)

def store_to_bucket(path, date):
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=date+ext, Body=data)
    print ("Done")
```

Not sure what the problem is with credentials? Has anyone experienced similar issue or knows how to fix it?

Found solution to my problem by fixing some code. UPdated version below:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = open("/home/pi/Desktop/pythonForAWS/certs/key.txt", 
"r").read()

ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = open("/home/pi/Desktop/pythonForAWS/certs/skey.txt", 
"r").read()

BUCKET_NAME = open("/home/pi/Desktop/pythonForAWS/certs/bucket.txt", 
"r").read()

def store_to_bucket(path, date):

    data = open(path, 'rb')
    ext = '.jpg'    

    s3 = boto3.resource(
        's3',
         aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
         aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
         config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
    )

    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key=date+ext, Body=data)

    print ("Done")
```

Comment: Please double-check the syntax of the Python in the question; as of now, it looks like the s3.Bucket().put_object() call is outside the function store_to_bucket, and Python has meaningful whitespace.

Comment: My apologies. Syntax is good in code forgot to tab it in this thread.

Comment: Not an answer, but a tip: since you already read the BUCKET_NAME from the file, why not reading the credentials too? Does the error persist if you read() them all at the beginning?

Comment: Hey Alex. Thanks for the tip. Although I had this checked before... During re-check I noticed mistahe in my code. I'm submitting updated version of code here. I hope this will help to someone xD

Comment: The situation is now clear; I will write the most likely cause as an answer, and if you want you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as it can be understood by the re-writing, you are creating the `s3` object inside the function, the reason for non-working can be the fact that you are calling `read()` multiple times on the same file object.

The first call returns the whole content of the file, but moves the "position" of the file object to the end, so subsequent calls of the same function return nothing - as there's nothing more to read.

Reading the value only once just works, as would `seek()`ing back to the beginning of the file and reading again each time. I'd advise to read the value only once, to avoid unnecessary I/O and related overhead.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! So can I assume now the code is structured properly? I will update it very soon to use threads. If you could send an advice, it would be very helpful before implementation, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, now it looks reasonable. Depending on personal preference, you may want to istantiate the s3 object only once, outside the function that actually uploads the file - but then your function will just be a one-liner. Make sure you check documentation for how to use boto3 in a multithreaded environment; existing code may not "just work" in a MT situation.